# Android back stack and page navigation

Tags: android, back-stack

My apps has 3 activities:

1. Activity1 is main activity.
2. Activity2 shows list of cars.
3. Activity3 stores new car in the database.

My activity navigation is like this:
Activity1 starts Activity2, and Activity2 starts Activity3.

Now, Activity3 will do some database related operation. After saving the data to the database. Activity3 starts Activity2.

So, when I use the following code in Activity3:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

the apps back stack looks like this:

```
Activity1 -> Activity2 -> Activity3 -> Activity2
```

However, when I use this code in Activity3:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

the apps back stack looks like this:

```
Activity1 -> Activity2 -> Activity2
```

**But, I don't want the aforementioned back stacks. I want the apps back stack to look like this:**

```
Activity1 -> Activity2
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should just call `finish()` in Activity3 rather than creating a new Intent.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want Activity3 to return to Activity2 after saving the data. The easiest way to do this is by calling `finish()`.